# javascript (applescript) : find text and highlight

Tags: javascript, text, safari, applescript

I'm trying to find every instance of some text and highlight them in safari, whatever the tab they are.

here is the code so far :

```
set myList to {"ask", "yesterday", "more random e.g"}
try
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on';" in tab 1 of window 1


        repeat with thisText in myList
            do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection();
                    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
                    while (window.find('" & thisText & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}
                    sel.collapseToEnd()" in tab 1 of window 1
        end repeat
        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off';" in tab 1 of window 1

    end tell
on error
    --
end try
```

issue with this code :

- The page will scroll down and up as the script run
- This won't search on every tabs
- If I click on a link / page refresh that won't work (I guess I can use a repeat but then I have the annoying scrolling issue)
- If possible I like every instance of one variable have the same colour, then different colour for another variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop to deal with all the tabs in the frontmost window like this:

```
set myList to {{"ask","#5cdf64"}, {"yesterday", "#FFFF00"}, {"more random e.g", "#FF0000"}}
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set theWindow to front window
    tell theWindow
        set tabCount to count of tabs
        repeat with tabIndex from 1 to tabCount
            set current tab to tab tabIndex
                tell current tab
                    repeat with colourPair in myList
                        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'"
                        do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.collapse(document.body, 0); while (window.find('" & (item 1 of colourPair) & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '" & (item 2 of colourPair) & "');}"
                        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off'"
                    end repeat
                end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Your JavaScript will then be pointing at the right tab without the need to hardcode references to the window and tab.

Your requirement to assign a different colour to each instance in myList is dealt with by a 'list of lists' with pairs of the search term and the colour code.

I think the scrolling is something to do with `sel.collapseToEnd()` which I don't think you need.

Comment: nice thank you, if I remove the sel.collapse this would not highlight  all the text (down the page) but then if I leave on the script is point less cause the page keep scrolling down and up

Comment: When I run the script over several tabs with several incidences of the search term on each, every one is highlighted without the sel.collapse - and it doesn't scroll.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t test it now but I will try in a min, thank for your help again

Comment: is this a way to do it without focusing on each tab ?

Comment: ok so instead everytab , I changed so it's only highlighting the focused tab.